# Veldrid: Only execute fragment shader

Tags: fragment-shader, uniform-buffer-object

Having an HLSL shader like this:

```
struct FragmentIn
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

struct Oct
{
    ...
};

float3 Camera;
float heading;
Oct data[9];

float4 FS(FragmentIn input) : SV_Target0
{
    ...
}
```

... how would one supply the uniforms and execute it directly for all pixels?

Using the [Veldrid](https://mellinoe.github.io/veldrid-docs/index.html) framework.

Comment: I don't know anything about Veldrid, but usually this is accomplished by having a single full-screen quad with a trivial geometry shader.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks, but how would I set the uniforms on the fragment shader?

Comment: From a quick look at the docs you linked I'd guess you use GraphicsDevice.UpdateBuffer on a DeviceBuffer whose type is [BufferUsage.UniformBuffer](https://mellinoe.github.io/veldrid-docs/articles/shaders.html#uniform-buffer).